# Fail to show an image using Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, web-development-server

I want to show an image in the homepage of a python web application. So far I wrote the following program:

**My directories and files**

```
myWebApp/
    app/
        __init__.py
        views.py
    templates/
        home.html
    static/
        Desert.jpg
    run.py
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views
```

**views.py**

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template
from flask import url_for

@app.route('/')
def root():
    imag = url_for ('static', filename = 'Desert.jpg')
    tle = "Hey"
    return render_template('home.html', imag,tle)
```

**home.html**

```
<html>
    <title>{{ tle }}</title>
    <body>
        <img src="{{ imag }}"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**run.py**

```
from app import app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And when I run the `run.py`, I receive the following *Internal Server Error*:

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: You can simply `<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='Desert.jpg') }}">`

Comment: To resolve problems in Flask more easily it a good idea to activate the debug mode as described in http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#debug-mode . But make sure it is off in production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the correct syntax for the `render_template` function. You need to use keyword arguments:

```
return render_template('home.html', imag=imag, tle=tle)
```